# Loop only through subdirs

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have the following directory structure

```
mkdir -p joe/{0,1}
mkdir -p john/0

tree 
.
├── joe
│   ├── 0
│   └── 1
└── john
    └── 0
```

And I want to call a program for each entry, in this case the program should be called 3 times, for `program joe/0`, `program joe/1` and `program john/0`

How can I do this in pure bash script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through `./*/*/`.

```
for arg in ./*/*/; do
  program "$arg"
  # if you don't want the trailing slash:
  # program "${arg%/}"
done
```

This is called **filename expansion**, and is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion).